# Check if file exists on my sever - node js

Tags: node.js, filesystems

When I'm using a url query like "http://localhost:8080/?file=index.js", I get always "the file doesn't exist".

The file do exist.
Any suggestions?

Purpose: Find if the file exists on my server. the file's name must be in the file parameter.

```
let http = require("http");
let fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    let url2 = req.url;
    if(fs.existsSync(url2.file)==true)
    {
        res.end("The file exists");
    }

    else{
        res.end("The file doesn't exists");
    }

}).listen(8080);
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.url` in your case will be `/?file=index.js`.  And, `url2.file` is `undefined` so when you do this:

```
if(fs.existsSync(url2.file)==true)
```

you're running:

```
if(fs.existsSync(undefined)==true)
```

which is never going to be true.

---

If you want a specific query parameter such as `file=index.js`, then you have to parse that URL into a data structure that will then allow you to access the `.file` property.

There are a couple ways to parse the query string.

1. You can use the [URL library](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_urlsearchparams) and parse the whole URL and it will then give you what it calls URLSearchParams.
2. You can get just the query string yourself and use the [queryString library](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) to parse just the query string into its piece.
3. You can use a framework like Express that parses the query string parameters for you automatically and puts them into `req.query`.

Here's an implementation using the queryString module:

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const querystring = require('querystring');

http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    let index = req.url.indexOf("?");
    if (index !== -1) {
        let qs = req.url.slice(index + 1);
        let qsObj = querystring.parse(qs);
        if (qsObj.file) {
            if (fs.existsSync(qsObj.file)) {
                res.end(`The file ${qsObj.file} exists`);
            } else {
                res.end(`The file ${qsObj.file} does not exist`);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    res.end("Invalid request, no file specified");

}).listen(8080);
```

Or, here's an implementation using the URL class:

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    urlObj = new URL(req.url, `http://${req.headers.host}`);
    let file = urlObj.searchParams.get("file");
    if (file) {
        if (fs.existsSync(file)) {
            res.end(`The file ${file} exists`);
        } else {
            res.end(`The file ${file} does not exist`);
        }
        return;
    }
    res.end("Invalid requeset, no file specified");

}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Added implementation using the queryString module.

Answer (score 0):

fs.existsSync is deprecated
[image]

you can use the new method fs.access to check if the file exists or not
and if you are reading or writing the file you should not check if it exists rather handle the error in the reading and writing file methods accordingly.